# SQL Date difference returns wrong result if date entered manually

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to find the difference between two dates by

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('27-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

it returns `-730492`, which is wrong as it should be `-5`. I have tried

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL; --(1)
SELECT TO_DATE('27-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL; -- (2)
```

the (1) returns `22-06-2017`, and the (2) returns `27-06-2017` as it should. Also if I try

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(SYSDATE + 5, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

It will return the correct value `-5`. Why when I try to find difference between manually entered data and the system generated one, I get the different result?

Comment: ***NEVER*** call `to_date()` on a value that *is* already a `DATE`. `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, ...` makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to wrap `SYSDATE` in `TO_DATE()`. It is already a date. What you are doing is implicit type conversion, and it is not needed here.

It takes your original statement: `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

And it is turning it into this: 
`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE), 'DD MONTH YYYY')`

Try replacing it with this line instead:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - TO_DATE('27-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I have used `to_date` in order to show that I need date in dd-mm-yyyy format, when I try your suggested method I  get -4.5.. result as it tries to take hours if I am not wrong. So do you think using `SELECT ROUND(SYSDATE - TO_DATE('27-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) FROM DUAL;` would be ok?

Comment: Try doing `TRUNC(sysdate)`. It is a decimal number, with 0 being midnight and .9999999 being 23:59:59. Therefore truncating it will give you the date only without the time component.

Comment: Better use `1 - 1/24/60/60` instead of `.9999999`